# Android SQLiteDatabase, how to use method replace()?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, replace

How to use the method [replace()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#replace(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) of SQLiteDatabase?

While writing code to DB I had the idea to search on google.
For example, in my case, I have an method **insert()** e **delete()** respectively for insert or remove one Note in DB, but if the Note already exist I should call first delete() and then insert().

While with method replace() how should I do?

It would be helpful if someone would write an example, thanks.

Comment: replace is rather try update if row exists if not insert ...

Comment: Yes, thanks for enlightening me ._.

Comment: Well, REPLACE is just a single instruction. I find it useful to INSERT or UPDATE with a single command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to use the `replace()` method, you need a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint on the table.

When you call `replace()`, the database tries to insert the row.
If this fails because of a uniqueness conflict, the existing row that caused the conflict is deleted before inserting the new row.

`replace()` is useless if you want to update a row.

Comment: I got it.. So, I have a PK that is an ID AUTOINCREMENT, this is why I was not replaced the element in DB... Any advice?

Comment: How do you identify the note to replace?

Comment: Unique(title, text) and ID is PK

Comment: I cannot see how that unique constraint would make sense. Anyway, to update a row, use `update()`.